# Подключение библиотеки после компиляции

Tags: java, eclipse, lib

Здравствуйте.

Как мне подключить библиотеку после компиляции программы?

У меня есть Eclipse, с созданным проектом, в проекте подключена библиотека, т.е в Eclipse самом проект спокойно запускается, а после компиляции пишет ClassNotFoundException, как мне подключить библиотеку, т.е library.jar.

Comment: Как-то так http://stackoverflow.com/q/4432440/5694145

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/8/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html